# Improving buffer smoothness using PyQGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, geometry, buffer, api

I am trying to automate buffering of objects in QGIS using Python. The function below using QgsGeometryAnalyzer works but the output is blocky. I understand that the smoothness of the buffer edge can be improved by [increasing the number segments per quarter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93425/qgis-radius-buffer-question-can-it-be-more-circular) but i am unsure of how to do this using Python or even if it is possible.

This [note and the linked github pull request](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2017-May/048444.html) suggests not.

Is there an alternate method i am missing that would allow me to increase the number of segments and so the smoothness of the buffer object?

```
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(LayerToBeBuffered, "Output.shp", 2000, False, False, -1)
```

[image: Blocky buffer object output from QgsGeometryAnalyzer]

Comment: You could also use the Processing algorithm `qgis:fixeddistancebuffer` which includes a parameter for segments :)

Comment: Beautiful. 
I amended to; 

import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", LayerToBeBuffered, 2000, 30, False, "Output.shp")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [buffer()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a1a7e3def7f450ebf7857c90e41083865) method. It applies to a geometry object. For example, using the following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # for example
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    buffered_geom = geom.buffer(200, 30) # this is the relevant part
```

you will create a buffer around the current feature with a radius of 200 (expressed in the units of measurement of the project) and composed of 30 segments.

Comment: I appreciate this would achieve a buffered object but would do so within the existing layer. I need the buffered object to be in a separate layer as with in the original snippet.

Comment: @benj you asked for a method and I answered mentioning a method. Instead, if you want to create the object in a new layer, you may follow the suggestion by Joseph (the **qgis:fixeddistancebuffer** algorithm works using the *buffer()* method).